# foreach with uri in

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hey looking through the net I can't seem to find a solution on how to pull these values out of this column of mine, I have only been developing for a year at Uni so this is all new to me.

Basically I don't know how to do it, and reading up on Linq to SQL as well as conditional statements and loops hasn't brought me any closer to finding my solution.

It's as simple as this statement below:

```cs
public void SendToast(string title, string message)
{
    var toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
        "<wp:Toast>" +
            "<wp:Text1>{0}</wp:Text1>" +
            "<wp:Text2>{1}</wp:Text2>" +
        "</wp:Toast>" +
        "</wp:Notification>";
    var messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toastMessage);
    using (clientsDBDataContext clientDB = new clientsDBDataContext())
    {
        var client = new ServiceFairy.clientURI();
        foreach (string r in client.uri)
        {
            Uri rs = new Uri(r.ToString());
            SendMessage(rs, messageBytes, NotificationType.Toast);
        }
    }
}
```

I know for a fact I am doing it wrong but I just cant get my hands on how to fix this, if it wouldn't be too much to ask, please explain how I am doing this wrong as I feel useless when I have to ask others to help me out with stuff I can't figure out myself.

Thanks :)

This is the error Message I am getting:

```sh
Error   1   Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this line doing?

```
var client = new ServiceFairy.clientURI();
```

Aside from the fact that this wouldn't compile (it needs to be `new ServiceFairy()`), what does `clientURI()` return?  You use it here like this:

```
foreach (string r in client.uri)
```

I suspect that `client.uri` is actually a *string*.  If not, what is it?  Assuming it's a string, then looping over any string in C# results in looping over the *characters* in the string.  So I expect your compiler error is due to the fact that you are declaring `r` as a `string`, but it's actually a `char`.  Most likely you don't need a loop at all, but I can't answer that until you explain what `client.uri` actually returns.

And if you're feeling generous, perhaps you can explain why you have a class named `ServiceFairy`. ;)

**Edit:**
Based on the comments, the code should go from:

```
var client = new ServiceFairy.clientURI();
foreach (string r in client.uri)
{
    Uri rs = new Uri(r.ToString());
    SendMessage(rs, messageBytes, NotificationType.Toast);
}
```

To:

```
var client = new ServiceFairy.clientURI();
Uri rs = new Uri(client.uri);
SendMessage(rs, messageBytes, NotificationType.Toast);
```

Comment: clientURI refers to the Table that I am using for my Data, I named my Linq2SQL clientsDB and the table within clientURI as the purpose is to mainly retrieve the URI associated with a clientID. client.uri should refer to the column uri inside the table, and yes its a string, I wasnt aware that looping over a string is actually looping over the characters, I was trying to retrieve the string thats stored in the column so I can use the string to message all the clients in the DB

Comment: lmao I wasnt sure what to call and learning it all was magical so I called it that, not sure =/ Dinsey channel was on TV xD

Comment: @John, yep, so just remove the loop, it's not needed.  And heh, yeah, I'm sure we've all succombed to Disney before. :P

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `client.uri` is just a single `string`, not an array of `string[]`.  So the `foreach` is iterating through each `char` in the string.

So you can change it to: `foreach(char r in client.uri) {...`  but I don't think that's what you want.

Just ditch the whole foreach loop and do:

```
Uri rs = new Uri(client.uri);
SendMessage(rs, messageBytes, NotificationtType.Toast);
```